# How to debug Network File Access in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, home-networking, file-sharing

I'm trying to enable file sharing access between 2 Windows 10 PCs.

1. Main PC
2. Surface

## Main PC

I already enabled this, and UN = `jdoe` PW = `allStar123!`

[image]

**Am I forgetting something else ?**

## Surface

I used these UN = `jdoe` PW = `allStar123!` to access my local account in my main Windows 10.

When I tried to connect from my Surface, I kept getting an error

> Password is wrong.

[image]

How do I debug this further ?

Comment: Try without the need for a password (bottom of the page in Control Panel on your screenshot). If you still get an error after rebooting both devices, then it's not a matter of the password being wrong, but of permissions on the folders you're trying to access from one device to the other. The latest Windows Update may have wreaked havoc on your sharing folders (it happened to me), and you may have to remove all permissions and start from scratch. Also disable Fast Startup on both devices before you restart them.

Comment: How do I reset the permission of even check if the current permission ?

Comment: Have you tried to enable access without the need for a password first? If so and it's still not working, you must right-click on each folder or directory you want to share, and "Remove access", then restart both devices with Fast Startup turned off, go back to your PC, right-click on each folder or directory again, and in Properties, select the Share tab, and name all the users you'll grant access to those folders or directories. I assume you're not working out of an Active Directory, so you must do it user by user. If you're the only user on both devices, it should be easy and quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the settings in your first screen shot have been made on both computers.
2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.
3. If you wish to share by computer name instead of IP address, put an entry in the main computer's HOSTS file with the name and IP address of the Surface.
4. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP and make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.
5. This next step depends on computer user names and passwords. If both computers use the same username and password, you can skip this step, restart both and test.

If the user names are different, do the following. Make a username on Main that is the Surface user name and password. Use this for permissions on the folders on Main you wish to share. It is normally quite difficult to share USER folders because Home Group was removed - security concerns. Use a neutral folder.

Again after all the above changes restart and test

Comment: I have 1 confirmed on both PC. How do I confirm 2 ?

Comment: I have enabled fast start up on both PC for fast remote access. Could this be the issue ?

Comment: Fast startup does not affect folder sharing. Open Advanced Network Sharing, select All Networks and password protected sharing is at the bottom. Make sure it is ON

Comment: Yes, it is on on both. Thanks for telling me how to check it.

Comment: Go through the steps I left for you (each one) to see if you can get folder sharing working

Comment: I can see it woking as soon as I reset the password to the local user of my main PC.

Comment: Thanks - good to know it is working.